# Making an array formula usable with Index

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I converted the results of an array of comma-separated words into usable data with an index formula.

The Index correctly lists all data. However, if the indexed list exceeds 33 words, I get a Value error and can no longer manipulate the index data.

Why the limit of 33 words? How can I go beyond this?

```
Array formula: =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$50000=1,$A$2:$A$50000, ""))
Index formula: =Index([Array],1)
Listing Index formula: =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE([Index],",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

Expected results: Generate a column list with an unlimited # of results (currently works with up to 33 results)

Actual results: 
The array formula generates a comma-separated list of matching words from a long word list (working)
The Index formula converts this list into a string that I can manipulate (working)
The Listing Index formula converts the comma-separated list into a column list (works if the indexed list is <=33!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've exceeded the maximum number of characters that SUBSTITUTE can return. SUBSTITUTE can only result in a string of 32,567 characters.

```
=SUBSTITUTE([Index], ",", REPT(" ", 999))
```

The above returns #VALUE! if the resulting expanded string is longer than 32,567, the maximum value of a signed short integer. Even without the actual text, 33 × 999 is 32,967.

btw¹, you are concatenating with `,<space>` as the delimiter but splitting the concatenated string by `,`. You should really choose one or the other.

btw², if your *array* string is less than half of 32,567 you should be able to use nested SUBSTITUTE functions or a SUBSTITUTE/REPLACE combination to get over the 33 item limit but there will still be limits. You cannot use worksheet formulas for 'an unlimited # of results'; you need VBA for longer strings.

The following minimizes the expansion of the original string by changing specific instances (SUBSTITUTE's fourth argument) to a single 'illegal' character which can be located easily among the rest of the original string.

```
=TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE([index], FIND(CHAR(9), SUBSTITUTE([index], ", ", CHAR(9), ROW(1:1))), LEN([index]), ""), 1, IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(9), SUBSTITUTE([index], ", ", CHAR(9), ROW(1:1)-1)), 0), ""))
```

CHAR(9) is the tab character and while it is ultimately possible to force a tab character into a cell, they are generally considered 'illegal' cell content so using them as a unique placeholder is pretty safe.

The following User Defined Function will split out any piece from virtually any size string.

```
Option Explicit

Function getPiece(str As String, ndx As Long, _
                  Optional delim As String = ", ")

    getPiece = Split(str, delim)(ndx - 1)

End Function

'usage on worksheet with default `comma><space>` as the delimiter
=getPiece([Index], row(1:1))
```

Put the above into a standard public module code sheet. Use Alt+F11 to open the VBE then Alt+I+M to insert a module code sheet into the project.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The array strings are well under .5(32,567). How can I use nested sub / sub replace to get over the current limit?

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much! One minor thing -- the list now stops after about 230 characters :/

Comment: See additions made above.